# Error: cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, lib

I am trying to install an externally managed package with the command `pip install package_name`. However, in the process I get the following error message, leading to failure of the installation:

```
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: skipping incompatible /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I do not understand the problem. For instance, `/lib64/` contains a link to `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Similar for `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`. My system runs on Kubuntu 23.04.

Comment: You need to include a lot more information, actual package name, logs, build system, its unclear what produces this problem.

Comment: @aspear – 
It appears that `ld` is outdated.